# Mandrill Template is sent correctly once every 28 times

Tags: c#, asp.net, mandrill

When I run the code below the Mandrill Template is sent correctly once every 28 times. Every other time it will send "Test_email". Does anyone know why this is? Can this be a trial version?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
```

Table

```
<table style="text-align: center; border-spacing:5px;  margin-left: auto;margin-right:  auto;vertical-align: middle;width: 600px;background-color:lightgrey; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;border-radius:15px;">

<tr>
    <td>Some Text here</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
namespace Messages
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("me@mail.com", "b");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress("ano@gmail.com", "To Name");
        const string fromPassword = "API Key";
        const string subject = "test template email";
        //const string body = "Test-email";
        TemplateContent tp = new TemplateContent();
        tp.name = "Test_email";


        var smtp = new SmtpClient
                   {
                       Host = "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
                       Port = 587,
                       EnableSsl = true,
                       DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                       UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                       Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)

                   };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                             {
                                 Subject = subject,
                                 Body = tp.name

                             })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are your mails listed in Mandrills dashboard? Are you receiving any mail to your senderMail (me@mail.com in your example)? Have you perhaps clicked around in the web interface and invalidated your api key?

Comment: Hi, yes mails are all listed in dashboard. I did not receive any mail to my senderMail. api key seems fine. I just created a new one and replaced old and still no go.

Comment: Does the dashboard show them as successful? Could your mailserver be down?

Comment: yes all delivered. seems fine. Do you see any issue with my code?

Answer (score 0):

If they're showing in the Outbound Activity, then your code was fine and Mandrill processed the mail.  Is the issue that it shows as delivered in Mandrill but you don't see it? Or that it doesn't look like the template was applied?  If you're sending to Gmail, you might see the content hidden because of the emails being included in a conversation.  Look for three dots to expand the information. If they all have the same subject line and content, then Gmail will hide previously-received content as part of the conversations feature.  If that's not the issue, then you should clarify exactly where you're seeing an issue in the process.

Comment: The template is emailed correctly once every 28 times. Every other email in between I get the text "Test-email"